# Connection issues with topics from which application is consuming is not being caught when I do bindingLifecycleController.queryState

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have an application which consumes from one topic(Lets call it inputTopic) and produces to another topic(lets call it outputTopic). I have written a custom HealthIndicator where I am trying to do the following:
Issues connecting to input topic : identify and log the error
Issues connecting to output topic: identify, log the error, pause the input topic binding

To simulate an error scenario I am giving wrong topic name.

Sample code is as below:

#Config in properties file

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumeSubscribeUnsubscribeEventMessage-in-0.destination={Wrong topic name}

#Code snippet

```
    try {
        Binding<?> inputMDESTopicBinding = bindingsLifecycleController.queryState("consumeSubscribeUnsubscribeEventMessage-in-0");
        inputMDESTopicBindingStatus = inputMDESTopicBinding.isRunning();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Topic A from which we are consuming is having issues");
    }
```

Here the exception is not caught and I dont get an error log.

#Config

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumeAccountUpdatesProduceLifeCycleEventMessage-out-0.destination={Wrong topic name}

#Code snippet

```
    try {
        Binding<?> inputMDESTopicBinding = bindingsLifecycleController.queryState("consumeAccountUpdatesProduceLifeCycleEventMessage-out-0");
        inputMDESTopicBindingStatus = inputMDESTopicBinding.isRunning();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Topic B to which we are producing is having issues");
        bindingsLifecycleController.changeState("consumeSubscribeUnsubscribeEventMessage-in-0", BindingsLifecycleController.State.PAUSED);
    }
```

Here the exception is caught.

Comment: The binding created incase of wrong output topic name is LateBinding which the gives a null pointer exception which can be caught to identify the issue.

Whereas the binding created incase of wrong input topic name in destination is AbstractMessageChannelBinder and the isRunning returns a true which is not the expected behavior

Comment: What do you mean by the wrong topic name above? Because when you provide a destination like that, the topic is automatically created by Kafka unless auto topic creation is disabled either through the binder or at the broker, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Providing a small sample application with instructions to reproduce the issue might be better. That way we can triage the matter further.

Comment: The auto create topic is set to false for both the broker and binder
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoCreateTopics=false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.autoCreateTopics=false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.autoCreateTopics=false

I tried not to provide any destination or group for the input topics, but still the binding state is shown as running and doesnt report an issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you ensure the topic is not created on the broker side? The binder level autoCreateTopics set to `false` means that the binder will not attempt to create the topic. The Kafka consumer may still create the topic if the broker allows it. You may want to double-check that the property `auto.create.topics.enable` is set to `false` on the broker side.
I created a quick sample app with a simple consumer against a Kafka cluster where the topic creation is disabled. The binding is not created since the topic is not available, and hence `bindingsLifecycleController.queryState` call does not return a corresponding binding. In fact, you will see exceptions thrown at application start-up since the binding cannot be created. As I indicated in the comments above, please create a small minimal sample app (probably with just a consumer) and then provide the configuration and instructions for us to reproduce the issue. That way we can triage it further.